# Connect GUI VPN On and Off automatically

Tags: r, cmd, automated-tests, vpn, rcpp

I use Windscribe as my VPN. It has a simple and elegant UI like this.

[image]

It runs when button clicked manually. But I frequently use it to bypass websites for Data Scraping purpose.

With a limited data byte, I am looking a way to launch it automatically on and off preferably with **Windows command line** or any script that can be **called from R Program** (I use R for Scrape).

So it will on for a while in a process of data scrape and then off immediately after its done. Is it possible to do this by script straight? (click the GUI button automatically)

EDIT: Rtools status in my console (but it still gives compile error on `rcpp`)

```
> library(pkgbuild)
> has_rtools()
[1] TRUE
> check_rtools()
[1] TRUE
```

Compile Error messages:

```
ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or compiler configuration errors!

make cmd is
  make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="file3c0434eb49ee.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file3c0434eb49ee.o"

make would use
"C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/library/Rcpp/include"     -fpermissive    -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c file3c0434eb49ee.cpp -o file3c0434eb49ee.o
if test "zfile3c0434eb49ee.o" != "z"; then \
  if test -e "file3c0434eb49ee-win.def"; then \
    echo "C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file3c0434eb49ee.dll file3c0434eb49ee-win.def file3c0434eb49ee.o    -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    "C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file3c0434eb49ee.dll file3c0434eb49ee-win.def file3c0434eb49ee.o    -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/bin/x64" -lR ; \
  else \
    echo EXPORTS > tmp.def; \
    "C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw64/bin/"nm file3c0434eb49ee.o | sed -n 's/^.* [BCDRT] / /p' | sed -e '/[.]refptr[.]/d' -e '/[.]weak[.]/d' | sed 's/[^ ][^ ]*/"&"/g'  >> tmp.def; \
    echo "C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file3c0434eb49ee.dll tmp.def file3c0434eb49ee.o    -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    "C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file3c0434eb49ee.dll tmp.def file3c0434eb49ee.o    -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    rm -f tmp.def; \
  fi \
fi

Program source:
  1: 
  2: // includes from the plugin
  3: 
  4: #include <Rcpp.h>
  5: 
  6: 
  7: #ifndef BEGIN_RCPP
  8: #define BEGIN_RCPP
  9: #endif
 10: 
 11: #ifndef END_RCPP
 12: #define END_RCPP
 13: #endif
 14: 
 15: using namespace Rcpp;
 16: 
 17: // user includes
 18: 
 19:   #include <windows.h>
 20:   #include <iostream>
 21:   #include <stdio.h>
 22: 
 23: 
 24: // declarations
 25: extern "C" {
 26: SEXP file3c0434eb49ee( ) ;
 27: }
 28: 
 29: // definition
 30: SEXP file3c0434eb49ee() {
 31: BEGIN_RCPP
 32: 
 33:   HWND TaskBar, Start;
 34:   TaskBar = FindWindow(NULL, "Windscribe"); // <-- Windscribe window name here
 35:   Start = FindWindowEx(TaskBar, 0, NULL, "Confirm"); // <-- connect button text here
 36:   PostMessage(Start, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
 37: 
 38: END_RCPP
 39: }

Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created!
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
                                       ^C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/include/R_ext/RS.h:74:37: error: 'parameter' declared as function returning a functionC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/include/R_ext/RS.h:74:50: error: expected ')' before ',' token #define Free(p)        (R_chk_free( (void *)(p) ), (p) = NULL)                        ~                         ^make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:245: file3c0434eb49ee.o] Error 1
```

I did attempt to customize the src part as this:

```
src <- '
  HWND TaskBar = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Windscribe")); // <-- Windscribe window name here;
  HWND Start = FindWindowEx(TaskBar, 0, NULL, "Confirm"); // <-- connect button text here
  PostMessage(Start, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
'
```

But unfortunately, the above produces the same compile error messages

Comment: You can use the `Rcpp` package to wrap C++ code that uses the Win32 API to locate the window and then click the button in question.

Comment: @br00t Thankyou, while I may not really fond of C++, I will definetely look deeper on it regarding UI Automation

Answer (score 1):

@Jovan here's some toy sample code that illustrates how you can use Windows functions `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx` to find a window and click a button in Rcpp, hope it is helpful!

```r
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

inc <- '
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdio.h>
'

src <- '
  HWND TaskBar, Start;
  TaskBar = FindWindow(NULL, "Windscribe"); // <-- Windscribe window name here
  Start = FindWindowEx(TaskBar, 0, NULL, "Confirm"); // <-- connect button text here
  PostMessage(Start, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
'

settings <- getPlugin('Rcpp')
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS <- paste('-fpermissive', 
                                   settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS, 
                                   sep = ' ')
fun <- cxxfunction(sig = signature(), 
                   body = src,
                   includes = inc,
                   plugin = 'Rcpp',
                   settings = settings)
fun()
```

Comment: thanks for this sample code :), but I am not sure how it works, since its giving the error: `error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Warning message:In system(cmd) : 'make' not found`

Comment: Should i change the windscribe into full path like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windscribe\Windscribe.exe` ?

Comment: @Jovan you will need to install RTools (<https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/>) on windows in order to compile C/C++ code. You will also need to take a look at the Microsoft API documentation (example <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa>) to glean what Windows API calls do.

Comment: Thanks for this guide, I will try to get to the workaround ASAP

Comment: I have installed Rtools and its environment path, but sorry I am stuck at the last compile error messages.